# How to find a windows firewall rule that's allowing access?

Tags: windows, firewall

I'm trying to disallow remote access of Tomcat's port 8080 and only allow localhost access, as far as I know (I'm not great at  Windows administration) Window's Firewall is default deny, so what I need to do is find and then disable the rule that's allowing remote access to Tomcat.

How do I do this? I've already looked through the existing inbound firewall rules and found nothing for port 8080 or any rules that seem like they'd allow HTTP through to port 8080 like this.

I've phrased the main question generically as I couldn't find anything that could help me determine which firewall rule is allowing this specific activity. Answers for my specific situation are appreciated, but I would prefer answers that explain how to find these firewall rules.

Comment: Won't be able to find the specific rule AFAIK. However, what I did was set both inbound and outbound rules to block for all firewall profiles, then disabled *all* firewall rules, and only allowed traffic based on EXE. Be forewarned though that Windows Update will add / enable FW entries after updates. I've mitigated this by creating a scheduled task that disables all fw rules that runs at startup. You could also run a "netstat -ano" to find the process running on that port, which may be helpful

Comment: Look for application policies instead of ports. The windows defender firewall is (from a services point of view) a lot more advanced than just a packet filter. It is able to track services, instances an their activity (like listening, connecting, ICMP and zones). Most service installer do register their applications there, so maybe thats what your tomcat did (it's done in a lot of installers).